# Windows license for instance run both on HW and in VM?

Tags: windows-7, license

I've been trying to figure out what license I need for Windows7 in order to run the same instance both on HW and in a VM.  Apparently it's not an OEM license ;)

**NB** Yes, I'm installing Windows just one single time, I just happen to want to boot it in two different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/briefs/win8-virtual.aspx

Basically one way:

**Cover it under Software Assurance**

You can enable rights using other methods VDA subscription or CSL subscription, but cost prohibitive.

Link to the SA site:
http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/software-assurance/default.aspx#tab=2

Comment: Ah, that's what I feared, I have to upgrade myself to a multi-million-dollar company first, then I can use my computer the way I'd like.  Well, well, I already knew that licenses tend to suck.  Thanks for helping me find this out.